# Can I use ArrayFormula with CountBlank or IsBlank, if so how?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

```
=IF(   OR(COUNTBLANK($F3)>0,
     COUNTBLANK($G3)>0,
     COUNTBLANK($H3)>0,
     COUNTBLANK($I3)>0),
     "Missing Values",
     $E3+(index(LSI_Index!$B$4:$B$40,MATCH(VLOOKUP($G3, LSI_Index!$A$4:$A$40,1),LSI_Index!$A$4:$A$40)))+(index(LSI_Index!$F$4:$F42, MATCH($H3,LSI_Index!$E$4:$E$42)))+(index(LSI_Index!$D$4:$D$38, MATCH($I3,LSI_Index!$C$4:$C$38)))-12.1)
```

The above works if I manually click and drag down the formula. However I would like to do something like either of these formulas below using `Arrayformula()` so I don't have to 'click drag' to copy down the formula.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN($A3:$A),IF(OR(COUNTBLANK($F3)>0,COUNTBLANK($G3)>0,COUNTBLANK($H3)>0,COUNTBLANK($I3)>0),"Missing Values",$F3:$F+(index(LSI_Index!$B$4:$B$40,MATCH(VLOOKUP($G3:$G, LSI_Index!$A$4:$A$40,1),LSI_Index!$A$4:$A$40)))+(index(LSI_Index!$F$4:$F42, MATCH($H3:$H,LSI_Index!$E$4:$E$42)))+(index(LSI_Index!$D$4:$D$38, MATCH($I3:$I,LSI_Index!$C$4:$C$38)))-12.1),))  


=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN($A3:$A),IF(OR(ISBLANK($F3:F),ISBLANK($G3:G),ISBLANK($H3:H),ISBLANK($I3:I)),"Missing Values",$F3:$F+(index(LSI_Index!$B$4:$B$40,MATCH(VLOOKUP($G3:$G, LSI_Index!$A$4:$A$40,1),LSI_Index!$A$4:$A$40)))+(index(LSI_Index!$F$4:$F42, MATCH($H3:$H,LSI_Index!$E$4:$E$42)))+(index(LSI_Index!$D$4:$D$38, MATCH($I3:$I,LSI_Index!$C$4:$C$38)))-12.1),))
```

I tried `CountBlank()` and I've tried `IsBlank()` but neither work.  You can see [in this spread sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CUz64SFbLEAWSqHJ-5dMapjjYdYKZggrl42euYrUWrU/edit?usp=sharing) what works and what doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to reduce the formula to the one below.

### Formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   IFERROR(
     E3:E6 + 
     VLOOKUP(G3:G6, temperature, 2, 1) + 
     VLOOKUP(H3:H6, alkalinity, 2, 1) + 
     VLOOKUP(I3:I6, calcium, 2, 1) - 
     12.1,
     "Missing values"
   )
 )

 copy / paste
 =ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(E3:E6 + VLOOKUP(G3:G6, temperature, 2, 1) + VLOOKUP(H3:H6, alkalinity, 2, 1) + VLOOKUP(I3:I6, calcium, 2, 1) - 12.1,"Missing values"))
```

### Explained

The fourth parameter in the `VLOOKUP` formula is optional and this is what's being said about that:

> Indicates whether the column to be searched (the first column of the specified range) is sorted, in which case the closest match for 'search_key' will be returned.

Setting it to `TRUE` will result in the desired result. The `IFERROR` will cover those instances were a value is missing, showing the text *Missing values*.

For very convoluted formula's it also helps to create named ranges.

### Example

I've added my solution to your example file.

Comment: Goodness, that is a way more elegant solution than what I was working at. Indeed named ranges will be my friend.

Comment: This is what I ended up using as I will be using it for a spreadsheet attached to a form. Thanks again. `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN($A3:$A),IFERROR($E3:$E + VLOOKUP($G3:$G, temperature, 2, 1) + VLOOKUP($H3:$H, alkalinity, 2, 1) + VLOOKUP($I3:$I, calcium, 2, 1) - 12.1,"Missing value(s)"),))`